# Is it possible to interchange the order of limits in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm stuck on this problem.

Let $g \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with $|x|^p  |D^{q} g| \rightarrow 0$ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$ for any nonnegative integers $p$ and $q$.

Suppose that $|g(\gamma)| \leq (1+\gamma^2)^{-1}$ for $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{|n|\leq NT} \frac{1}{T}g\left(\frac{n}{T}\right) = \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{|n|\leq NT} \frac{1}{T}g\left(\frac{n}{T}\right).$$

It is just interchange of the order of limits. But how can we guarantee this equality?

Any help will be appreciated!

**(edit) I've checked that 
$$ \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{|n|\leq NT} \frac{1}{T}g\left(\frac{n}{T}\right) = \int_{-N}^N g(\gamma) \, d\gamma,$$
so that $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{|n|\leq NT} \frac{1}{T}g\left(\frac{n}{T}\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(\gamma) \, d\gamma. $$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the assumptions imply that both sides are zero by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. This means that indeed you can change the order, but is this what you're asking for?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz That is not what I'm asking for. I obtained the LHS of the above equality from $\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{|n|\leq NT} T^{-1} g(n T^{-1}) = \int_{-N}^{N} g(\gamma) \, d\gamma$, so I think that the LHS is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(\gamma) \, d\gamma$. I'm gonna edit the question a little bit.

Comment: You're right, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us look at the RHS. Since $|g(x)| \le C_1 (1+x^2)^{-1}$, the series is absolutely convergent and 
$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{|n|\leq NT} \frac{1}{T}g\left(\frac{n}{T}\right) =  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{T}g\left(\frac{n}{T}\right) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g_T(x) \, dx, $$
where $g_T$ is a piecewise constant approximation of $g$: 
$$ g_T(x) = g(n/T) \quad \text{for } \frac{n}{T} \le x < \frac{n+1}{T}, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}. $$

We can assume that $|g'(x)| \le C_2 (1+x^2)^{-1}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Due to the Lagrange mean value theorem, for any $\frac{n}{T} \le x < \frac{n+1}{T}$ we can choose $\theta \in [n/T,x]$ such that $g(x)-g(n/T) =(x-n/T) g'(\theta)$. Since $|\theta| \ge |x|-1$ and $|x-n/T| \le 1/T$, 
$$ |g_T(x)-g(x)| \le |x - \frac{n}{T}| \cdot |g'(\theta)| \le \frac{1}{T} \cdot C_2(1+(|x|-1)^2)^{-1}. $$
Thus obtained function is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, hence 
$$ \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} g_T(x) \, dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \, dx \right| 
\le \frac{C_2}{T} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{dx}{1+(|x|-1)^2} 
\xrightarrow{T \to \infty} 0. $$
This means that both sides are in fact equal to $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \, dx$.

Comment: I think you lose the factor $1/T$ out of the first integral.

Comment: You're right. I'll correct this.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thanks! It is much simpler than I expected. However, I think that initial condition '$|g(x)| \leq (1+x^2)^{-1}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$' in the original statement is redundant. I think you could assume $|g'(x)| \leq C_2(1+x^2)^{-1}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ from the fact that $g'(x)$ and $x^2 g'(x)$ are both "rapidly decreasing". So, I think it would be fine without assuming '$|g(x)| \leq (1+x^2)^{-1}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$' to show our problem. Because we can obtain such assumption by considering $g(x)$ and $x^2 g(x)$.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz By the way, in your answer, I think it is better to use $|\theta| \geq |x| -1$ than $|\theta| \leq |x|+1$ to obtain an appropriate upper bound.

Comment: @cdamle You're right, I've edited the answer. As for the decay estimates, indeed they both come from the Schwartz-regularity assumption. I didn't attempt to make the assumptions minimal.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thanks. Could you explain what the Schwartz-regularity assumption is? Is it just the first line in the question?

Comment: @cdamle Yes, exactly. You can look up the definition of Schwartz functions [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). This class of functions is often used in Fourier analysis because of its Fourier transform invariance.